# Need to restart network interfaces and kill wpa_supplicant, how to fix?

Tags: networking, wpa-supplicant

My workplace uses 802.11x authentication for their WiFi network, and several times per day I get booted from the network and need to do the following:

1. Disable networking
2. sudo kill -9
3. Restart networking

At this point, the machine will connect to the network just fine. I don't see any weirdness in the syslog, and am running Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit). What could be wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem. It turns out that Network manager is a little overzealous in switching between access points (AP's) when more than one are present. You have two options

1. Use iwlist to find out how many AP's are there:

   ```
   root@debian:/home/nofrills# iwlist wlan0 scan

   Scan completed :
     Cell 01 - Address: 00:1E:58:A1:41:87
               ESSID:"iiserk_wireless"
               Mode:Managed
               Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
               Quality:4/5  Signal level:-64 dBm  Noise level:-92 dBm
               IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                   Group Cipher : TKIP
                   Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                   Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
                  Preauthentication Supported
               Encryption key:on
               Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                         12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                         48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s

     Cell 02 - Address: 00:1E:58:A1:54:7B
               ESSID:"iiserk_wireless"
               #More such details
   ```

   Then note the **Address** of the cell with the highest **Quality**. That is the AP nearest to you. Then click on Network manager applet, select "Edit Connections" and go to the wifi network listed. There will be a text box titled "BSSID". Paste the Cell address there.
2. Otherwise, you can ditch network manager altogether and use wpa_supplicant (Network manager uses it under the hood anyway). Just create a configuration file and edit your /etc/network/interfaces this way:

   ```
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback

   auto wlan0
   iface wlan0 inet dhcp
       pre-up wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -i wlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
       post-down killall -q wpa_supplicant
   ```

Option 1 is not very useful unless you spend most of your time at workplace in roughly the same location. Option 2 is what I am using now, and it works pretty well. But wifi does not get automatically reconnected after suspend/resume, so you need to run `/etc/init.d/networking/restart` manually.

If you like doing things neatly, as an alternative to the generic `killall` command, you can use the WPA specific tool `wpa_client`:

```
wpa_cli -i wlan0 terminate
```

Comment: Very helpful answer! Unfortunately I think your configuration of /etc/network/interfaces in your 2nd point wasn't pasted in. Can you please re-add it?

Comment: Oops! My bad. Added it.

Comment: You probably mean "/etc/init.d/networking restart". Oddly enough it hangs at "reconfiguring network interfaces" forever. What could be  the problem?

Answer (score 0):

sudo service network-manager stop

It will stop NetworkManager