# Wifi Doesn't Work After Suspend (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, wireless

Before I start this, I have tried all the solutions on various other posts and none have worked for me. I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a Dell Vostro 270S. Everything is smooth except after coming back after a suspend, the wifi does not work. Networks are detected but it is not able to connect to any. What can I do guys?

my wifi driver info if needed
 driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-53-generic

Comment: Some people have had luck  going around this issue by manually killing `wpa_supplicant`. Have you tried that?

Comment: how do i kill it? sorry i am very new

Comment: Killing `wpa_supplicant` via `sudo kill -9 wpa_supplicant` [seems to solve this problem for some people.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+bug/1311257) It may be because there are [two networks with the same ESSID](http://askubuntu.com/questions/209596/need-to-restart-network-interfaces-and-kill-wpa-supplicant-how-to-fix).

Comment: I also suggest for you to upgrade to 16.04 LTS where most of these problems are resolved.

Answer (score 1):

so I ended up doing what darksky suggested and updated to 16.10, which solved the issue. I went with 14.04 because I thought 16.10 would lag on my hardware but that does not seem to be an issue. Thank you everyone for the help!